# ExampleMatcher.withIgnorePath is fetching property path that is ignored

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity which has multiple property paths. I used Query By Example and ExampleMatcher to ignore some of the property path.

My entity looks like below,
Employee.class

```java
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String designation;
```

I wanted to show only the Name and Id from the entity(fields in the table). For that, I did the following,

```java
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues().withIgnorePaths("designation");
Example<Employee> example = Example.of(entity, exampleMatcher);
```

But, the response returns all the values including the property given in the ignorePath.

Kindly assist me on how to ignore the property paths.

Comment: Never used an `ExampleMatcher`, but have you tried putting the `matching()` call at the end of that line instead of beginning?

Comment: 'the response returns all the values including the property given in the ignorePath' - did you mean that the results are *filtered* according to the value of `designation`, or that the value of `designation` is present in the response entities? These are two very different requirements

Comment: The value of `designation` is present in the response entity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`withIgnorePaths("designation")` prevents query-by-example from applying a *filter* based on the example's `designation` value. It does **not** prevent `designation` from being populated in the query result.

If you want to exclude certain properties from the query result, use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) or [query graphs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) (depending on which is a better fit for your particular use case). Not sure if there's a way they can be used with query-by-example, though.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if this will work

```
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("designation").withIgnoreNullValues();
```

I just added `withIgnorePaths` first.

Refering to [This link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/query-by-example.adoc)